# Getting error with $conn->set_charset('utf8');

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like someone to explain me what is going on. I am using Cyrillic letters and to avoid question marks I use set_charset, but I have the following error:

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Only one usage of each
>   socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\application\configs\dbconfig.php on line 7 The
>   following error occurred: Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

Code:

```
$connection = new mysqli($hostname, $dbname, $dbpass, $database);
$connection->set_charset('utf8');
```